# Spring Boot Data obtains Asian symbols in a Lob-type column

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm extracting data from a SQLServer running on[Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux) database but when I extract the data with JpaRepository this is what I get:

[image: JavaObject].

I am saving an sql query that can be very large, so I use Lob, but when I use DataGrip to verify if the information is correct, don't have any Asian symbols.

```
@Column
@Lob
private String sql;
```

> Windows10 - Spring Boot 2.1.2 - mssql-server-linux on Docker

Comment: By any chance are you storing an ASCII (`varchar`) string as a varbinary, and converting it back to a unicode (`nvarchar`) string? For example `SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),CONVERT(varbinary(MAX),'This is my string, with some characters in it'));` returns `N'桔獩椠⁳祭猠牴湩Ⱨ眠瑩⁨潳敭挠慨慲瑣牥⁳湩椠t'`.

Comment: I have not made any conversion, I use spring-data and hibernate to perist to database, the data type of the column is varchar (max)